# How to create Scheduled skype online meeting link programatically by python/django?

Tags: python, django, skype

I want to create skype meeting link like  "join.skype.com/YHeJdxncAImN" programatically in python , that we get when we click "create  a free meeting " button in https://www.skype.com/en/free-conference-call/ . After getting the link i'll send it through email to user to connect the meeting ...I am very new in django . Please help me.. Thank you in advance ...

Comment: this question isnt for stackoverflow. please show us some code you wrote we can help you with. Did you check if skype has an API?

Comment: You can directly search it to google, you will have lots of result

Comment: @hansTheFranz, I not able to write any code, thats why I'm asking..I dont find any url to hit and get response

Comment: @vpdiongzon, I dont find any suitable reference, thats why I'm asking